# ReactJS - How to migrate from json-server to a .json file?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have this db.json and I want to migrate to file. How do I implement it? I had tried this way above and it didn't work for me. When I put the file in src folder, there appears an error message:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'houses.json' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\dir\src'

It does the same thing when I put the file in the public folder.

It is my db.json file:

```
 {   "houses": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Title here",
       "text": "Text here",
       "photos": [
         "pic1",
         "pic2",
         "pic3"        
      ]
     },
     "houses": [
     {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Title here",
       "text": "Text here",
       "photos": [
         "pic1",
         "pic2",
         "pic3"        
       ]
     },
     "houses": [
     {
       "id": 3,
       "name": "Title here",
       "text": "Text here",
       "photos": [
         "pic1",
         "pic2",
         "pic3"        
       ]
     } 
 }
```

I had traded this line

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:3001/houses';
```

for this other

```
 const URL = require('houses.json');
```

And it caused the error message showed before.

And how do I fetch these datas from axios? I was fetching datas from json-server doing this way below. It was successfully. I want to do the same thing but not from json-server but using .json file.

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:3001/houses';

class House extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      totalHouses: [],
      currentHouse: [],
      name: [],
      photos: [],
      text: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          totalHouses: Object.keys(res.data),
          currentHouse: res.data
        })
      })
  }

//...rest of the code omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example how to achieve what you need, while preserving your state approach.

```
const houses = require('./houses.json');

class House extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      totalHouses: [],
      currentHouse: [],
      name: [],
      photos: [],
      text: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      totalHouses: Object.keys(houses.data),
      currentHouse: houses.data
    })
  }

  //...

}
```

You can also achieve it without `componentDidMount`:

```
const houses = require('./houses.json');

class House extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      totalHouses: Object.keys(houses.data),
      currentHouse: houses.data
      name: [],
      photos: [],
      text: []
    };
  }

  //...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `require('./houses.json');`. Right now it looks for this file inside node_modules or even higher.

Comment: It didn't work. The error messages disappear but it didin't render nothing on the  screen

Comment: If you store your `houses.json` file inside your project, you have to `require` it using relative path, from the file you are requiring it in. If you require without `./` (or maybe `../../directory/with/file/file.json`), it will be treated like npm package. Just like you would do `const _ = require('underscore')` - notice there is no `./` here.

Comment: I put this file one into the 'src' folder and another into 'public' folder

Comment: it is inside my project

Comment: In what directory is the file you are trying to require it from?

Comment: I put a copy into 'src' folder and another one into 'public' folder

Comment: 'src' is the same root of my component.js file and 'public'  is one folder above

Comment: I did two copies to be easier to catch one, and after I will delete the useless copy

Comment: One more question: isn't the file you are trying to require named `db.json`? If so, you just have to change `houses.json` to `db.json`.

Comment: the file name is 'houses.json'

Comment: By the way, if you require your houses via a file, you don't have to use axios any more. So just do `const houses = require('./houses.json')` and use `houses` the same as you would use axios response.

Comment: what are the advantages/disadvantage between 'json-server' and 'json file'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188752/discussion-between-piotr-szlagura-and-claudiobitar).